# VSTS Assembly Version in Release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've recently started using VSTS to build a Xamarin Forms App for iOS.  I have it build using a hosted macos agent and then releasing it to a container in our Azure Blob Storage.  The one thing I can solve at the moment, is how to include the Assembly Version in the name of the ipa file?

We're using an Enterprise license, so the ipa doesn't end up on any Store.  At the moment I have the App_Name.ipa file and all previous versions App_Name.1.0.0.ipa in the container, however it's always App_Name.ipa that is downloaded.

I thought that it might be an option to parse the AssemblyInfor.cs file and extra the version and then set an environment variable - however I don't seem to be able to access the variable in the Release stage.

Ideally I'd like all this to stay is VSTS, however I don't mind trigger a WebJob to perform some extra tasks, however the version number doesn't appear to be accessible from the ipa file.

Can anyone suggest an approach?

Comment: When you read, parse the file and use the value, what build number is displayed in the UI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use some related extension tasks to get Assembly Version from `AssemblyInfor.cs` files.

Such as you can use [**Assembly Info Reader**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kherzog.AssemblyInfoReader) task, and then you can get the Assembly Version by the variable `$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - when I set this during the build phase, will it be available in release? I will try this later today

Comment: Yes, you can add the task in release, then the variable can be used.

Comment: I tried running the task, however it doesn't work on the macos hosted build agent - and when run in release, there's no AssemblyInfo file.  I ended up adding the AssemblyInfo file to the Copy Files task in build.  It's not 100% ideal, but I now have access to the build number!

Comment: Excellent hint for me. I now use Assembly version loader. This uses the dll instead of a code file. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AppiePau.AssemblyVersionLoader